# How to consume DataTable in ASP.net webservice with PHP

Tags: c#, php, soap, webservice-client

I have a soap webservice that have written with C#.
I want consume it in php.
can datatable pass to web service as input parameter? 
I want to call below function in my php code with soap library:

this function is in server side
`GenerateBill(int CityCode, int Date, int AgentCode, int GenType, DataTable Input, ref DataTable Output, ref DataTable CustomersError, ref string ErrorMsg)`

Also, the Input variable in the function have three parameters.
I tried to solve the problem with a different approach! But the soap library(in php side) returned Error like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property in /var/www/html/wsabfa/genBillBatch.php

help me how to achieve this or suggest me how to do this if datatable is not possible.

Regards,